# Is “créneau théâtral” an accurate translation of “theatrical window”?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, expressions, terminologie, cinéma

The *theatrical window* is described as the period of time between when a film is released in theaters and on physical media (e.g. Blu-Ray, DVD, etc.). [It generally takes about 16 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_distribution#Standard_release).

I recently translated the sentence:

> Would the film industry be better off without the **theatrical window**?

as:

> Est-ce que l'industrie cinématographique vaudrait mieux sans le **créneau théâtral**?

To my understanding, *créneau* can be used to figuratively describe such a period of time, and *théâtral* can be used to describe something pertaining to theater, and in modern times relating to *films*.

So, is "créneau théâtral" an accurate translation of "theatrical window"? Is my translation as a whole accurate?

---

Le *theatrical window* (*créneau theatral*?) est décrit comme la période de temps entre la sortie d'un film aux théâtres et aux médias numériques (par ex. Blu-Ray, DVD, etc.). [Cela prend d'habitude 16 semaines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_distribution#Standard_release).

J'ai traduit récemment:

> Would the film industry be better off without the **theatrical window**?

comme:

> Est-ce que l'industrie cinématographique vaudrait mieux sans le **créneau théâtral**?

A ce que je comprends, *créneau* peut être utilisé pour décrire au sens figuré une telle période de temps, et *théâtrale* peut être utilisé pour décrire quelque chose se rapportant au théâtre, et aujourd'hui aux choses relatives aux *films*.

Donc, « créneau théâtral » est-elle une traduction juste de « theatrical window » ? Ma traduction est-elle juste dans l'ensemble?

Comment: En complément de la réponse donnée et pour acquérir le vocabulaire lié à ce domaine : http://www.cnc.fr/web/fr/ressources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the field of theatrical movie release, a specific terminology is used in France.

- "Window," in the sense of a time period during which the movie is released to a certain channel, is usually translated as "fenêtre." "Créneau" could be understood but is less used.
- "Theatrical release" is "sortie en salles" or "exploitation en salles."
- It is definitely **not** anything "théâtral," as that adjective would be understood as referring to stage theater. (So your translation can only likely be understood by someone who'd understand the mistranslation, and backtranslates into English.)
- The English "movie theater" is "une salle de cinéma," not "un théâtre."

A better translation of

> Would the film industry be better off without the theatrical window?

would be

> Le secteur du cinéma se porterait-il mieux sans la fenêtre d'exploitation en salles ?

Comment: Cool, I learn something new every day! Thanks for your answer!